# lim inf and lim sup question

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, lebesgue-measure, algebras

Denote $\mu$ to be the Lebesgue measure on $(0,1]$, $\{K_{n}\}$ a sequence of sets, and $\mathcal{B}(0,1]$ the borel sigma algebra on $(0,1]$. What would be an example of an $\{K_{n}\} \subseteq \mathcal{B}(0,1]$ s.t. $\mu(\lim \inf) \neq \mu(\lim \sup)$?

I have been thinking about it for awhile now and can't come up with anything. The help would be appreciated!

Comment: $$A_{2n}=(0,\tfrac13)\qquad A_{2n+1}=(\tfrac13,1)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this: for $n\geq 2$ define
$$A_n = \left\{ \begin{matrix}
(0, \frac{1}{2}] & \mbox{ if $n$ is even} \\
[\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{n} , 1- \frac{1}{n}]  & \mbox{ if $n$ is odd} 
\end{matrix}
\right.
$$

Then

$\liminf_n A_n = [\frac{1}{3} , \frac{1}{2}]$, so its measure is $\frac{1}{6}$

$\limsup_n A_n = (0,1)$, so its measure is $1$

But $\mu(A_n)$ oscillates between $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: What about $\lim \inf \mu(A_{n})$ and $\lim \sup \mu(A_{n})$? What will those be?

Comment: They are $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$. I thought it was clear.

Comment: Okay it is. Sorry about that. Was over thinking it.